# How to handle multiple results from a coroutine function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, generator, coroutine

I have some generators doing some searching stuff, and I use another generator wrapping them up:

```
def searching_stuff_1():
    # searching
    yield 1
    # and searching
    yield 2
    yield 3

def searching_stuff_2():
    yield 4
    yield 5


def gen():
    yield from searching_stuff_1()
    yield from searching_stuff_2()

for result in gen():
    print(result)
```

So now I am wondering how I can rewrite it into async version, that can yield multiple values in searching_stuff_1 and searching_stuff_2.

I was trying:

```
import asyncio

async def searching_stuff_1():
    f = asyncio.Future()
    result = []
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    #searching
    result.append(1)
    #searching
    result.append(2)
    result.append(3)
    f.set_result(result)
    return f

async def searching_stuff_2():
    f = asyncio.Future()
    result = []
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    result.append(4)
    result.append(5)
    f.set_result(result)
    return f

async def producer():
    coros = [searching_stuff_1(), searching_stuff_2()]
    for future in asyncio.as_completed(coros):
        yield await future

async def consumer(xs):
    async for future in xs:
        for r in future.result():
            print(r)
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(consumer(producer()))
loop.close()
```

However, in this version, I have to append all results into a list and wrap it in a Future instance. I am wondering if there is better way to handle multiple results from coroutine function. Is it possible that I can still yield those numbers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can still yield those numbers in async version, this is [Asynchronous Generators](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0525/), You can use async for[(PEP492)](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0492/) and Asynchronous Comprehensions[(PEP530)](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0530/), like this, rewrite from your first example. though this require python version higher than or equals to 3.6

```
import asyncio


async def searching_stuff_1():
    # searching
    yield 1
    # and searching
    yield 2
    yield 3


async def searching_stuff_2():
    yield 4
    yield 5


async def gen():
    async for i in searching_stuff_1():
        yield i
    async for i in searching_stuff_2():
        yield i


async def gen_all():
    return [i async for i in gen()]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    result = asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(gen_all())
    print(result)
```

for wishing to run two async generator async, you can use `asyncio.gather`.
But since `asyncio.gather` only collect coroutines' result in an async manner, you need to combine each yielded result from async generator separately with `async def gen2` before calling asyncio.gather,

```
async def gen2(coro):
    return [i async for i in coro()]


# combine two async
async def gen_all2():
    return list(chain.from_iterable(await gather(gen2(searching_stuff_1), gen2(searching_stuff_2))))
```

To prove my point, we can change `searching_stuff` to:

```
async def searching_stuff_1():
    print("searching_stuff_1 begin")
    # searching
    yield 1
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    # and searching
    yield 2
    yield 3
    print("searching_stuff_1 end")

async def searching_stuff_2():
    print("searching_stuff_2 begin")
    yield 4
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    yield 5
    print("searching_stuff_2 end")
```

and then make the move:

```
result = asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(gen_all())
print(result)

> searching_stuff_2 begin
> searching_stuff_1 begin
> searching_stuff_2 end
> searching_stuff_1 end
> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: But this one is not running asynchronously, although it's using async keyword, searching_stuff_1 is blocking searching_stuff_2. While in my async version sample code, you can tell that is running asynchronously by changing the sleep time. 
So I thought I have to use "yield await" to make it asynchronously, but it requires an awaitable item.

Comment: If you wish to run both searching_stuff(x) async, you can use gather for the job, I have updated my answer